# What percentage of a Qui Tam is recovered?

Tags: us-federal-government, federal-courts, from-the-latin

In the case of a Qui Tam filing with the United States attorneys office what percentage of the recovered damages go to the person that filed with the office?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qui Tam, a Latin legal term translated to:

> [he] who sues in this matter for the king as well as for himself.

This way of litigation is commonly known as Whistleblowing litigation, for someone to file a successful Qui Tam they must show the way that the opposing party is defrauding the government.

If the United States government decided to join in on the Qui Tam case, the person who filed it can look forward to receiving [15 to 25 percent](https://www.phillipsandcohen.com/whistleblower-rewards/) of the damages recovered, under the [False Claims Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_Claims_Act).